# Get updated value from EditText in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, baseadapter

I have a DialogFragment in which there is ListView, each ListItem has three TextViews and one EdiText, EditText allows integer values which can be changed as per the user requirement. So onClick of positive button of dialog I want to send thoes updated Integer value to the server.
While fetching EditText's text it fetches the old values not the updated one.

The code I have written

```
 View v;

    ArrayList<String> edValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    EditText et;

                            for (int i = 0; i < alObj.size(); i++) {
                                v = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
                                et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.user_bill_edit);
```

//Dialog

```
public class CaseUserList extends DialogFragment  {


    private Context context;
    private String pipeSeparatedUserLists;
    Boolean isOperationEdit = false;
    String strCaseId = null;
    private UserBillRateAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Object> alObj;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        context = getActivity();
        strCaseId = getArguments().getString(CaseConstants.TABLE_CASE_LIST_CASE_ID);
        //isOperationEdit = getArguments().getBoolean("isEdit");

        //Send network request to get the list
        new userBillRateList().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        //Prepare the list layout
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_case_user_list, null);
        builder .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("Update", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        View v;
                        ArrayList<String> edValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                        EditText et;

                        for (int i = 0; i < alObj.size(); i++) {
                            v = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
                            et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.user_bill_edit);
                            edValues.add(et.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        CaseUserList.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

    /**
     * Async task to fetch list of all possible Witness
     */
    private class userBillRateList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Object>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Object> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Network billRateList = new Network(getActivity(),CaseConstants.SERVICE_CASE_USER_BILL_RATE
                    + Constants.CONSTANT_CONTACT_ID + ","
                    + strCaseId);

            return HelperFunctions.convertJsonToDataModel(billRateList.getJsa_Output(),
                    UserBillingRateModel.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<Object> arrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
            alObj = arrayList;
            ListView allListsView = (ListView) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.list_view_case_user_list);

            if(arrayList.isEmpty()) {
                ((TextView) getDialog().findViewById(R.id.user_list_empty_text_view)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                ((EditText)getDialog().findViewById(R.id.user_list_search)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter = new UserBillRateAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);

                allListsView.setAdapter(adapter);
                allListsView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            }
            getDialog().show();
        }
    }
}
                                    edValues.add(et.getText().toString());
                                }
```

//Adapter

```
public class UserBillRateAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /**
     *  The following variable contains the File list in the CloudFileList bean format.
     */
    private ArrayList<Object> al_List;
    /**
     * The context of the activity being worked on
     */
    private Context context;
    ViewHolder viewContainer = null;
    ArrayList<Object> alDataObj;

    public UserBillRateAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> al_List){
        this.al_List = al_List;
        this.context = context;
        alDataObj = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(al_List != null)
            return al_List.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return al_List.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Long.valueOf(((UserBillingRateModel) al_List.get(position)).ContactId);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View viewConvert, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewContainer = null;
        if(viewConvert == null) {
            viewConvert = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_user_bill_list, null);
            viewContainer = new ViewHolder();
            viewContainer.txtUserName = (TextView) viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.user_name_txt);
            viewContainer.txtUserRole = (TextView) viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.user_role);
            viewContainer.txtUserRate = (TextView) viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.user_bill_txt);
            viewContainer.edUserRate = (EditText) viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.user_bill_edit);
            viewConvert.setTag(viewContainer);
        } else
            viewContainer = (ViewHolder) viewConvert.getTag();

        final UserBillingRateModel beanListItem = (UserBillingRateModel) al_List.get(position);
        viewContainer.txtUserName.setText(beanListItem.FullName);
        viewContainer.txtUserRate.setText(beanListItem.BillingRate);
        viewContainer.txtUserRole.setText(beanListItem.RoleName);
        viewContainer.edUserRate.setText(beanListItem.BillingRate);
        return viewConvert;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtUserName;
        TextView txtUserRole;
        TextView txtUserRate;
        EditText edUserRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you sending those variables and where are you updating them in your UI?

Comment: can you post your dialog and adapter code over here?

Comment: You should simply get child view from listView using _getChildAt(i)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `adapter.getView(i)` with `yourListView.getChildAt(i)`.
I suppose it will help.

Comment: You welcome ;) please mark an answer as correct. You can also upvote it if you wish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter add text change listener like

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //store value in your POJO class
        // like getItem(position).setUserEnterValue(s.toString());
    } 

});
```

on positive button click get value from adapter like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < alObj.size(); i++) {
   edValues.add(list.getAdapter().getItem(i).getUserEnterValue());
 }
```